# Cannot build Anjuta default GTK project

Tags: build, gtk, anjuta

I've just installed Anjuta on Ubuntu. I tried building the auto-made GTK(simple) project but I get the following error :

"Error: Directory `/home/cookie . Cie' does not look like the top-level package directory"

My project directory is named "PSE Anjuta Cie" so the mentionned directory looks like the end of the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to remember that there were some issues with project names with spaces. The problem is not really with Anjuta itself, but with the build system used by Anjuta.

In my Anjuta (version 3.14.1), defining a project with spaces produces an error dialog, which was added just for this:

[image]